# Windows 10 app settings menu implementation

Tags: cordova, cordova-win10

I'm building a Windows 10 app using Cordova and want to add Settings menu content, which can be found when clicking the 'hamburger' icon at the top-left.
How/where to do this?

Comment: Please provide more information. Which icon do you mean? Do you have any source code describing your problem?

Comment: @Beat Open any app on Windows 10 and look at the top left. There is a hamburger icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a WinRT API :

```
var settingsPane = Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.getForCurrentView();
function commandsRequested(e) {
    var applicationCommands = e.request.applicationCommands;
    var command1 = new Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsCommand('<commandId1>', '<Title>', function () {
        // do something...
    });
    applicationCommands.append(command1);
}
settingsPane.addEventListener("commandsrequested", commandsRequested);
```

You can execute this code in the DeviceReady handler and include it in a merge script for windows platform, in a custom plugin or just use a condition like following :

```
if (cordova !== undefined && cordova.platformId === "windows" && Windows) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately the SettingsPane is deprecated nowadays and not working in combination of Cordova anymore.